# Unable to add data in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

[code for uploading data in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q09MV.png)

Console:  "Document written with ID:  undefined"

```
try {
  console.log
  const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    name: "Alan",
    //middle: "Mathison",
    //last: "Turing",
    //born: 1912
  });
  console.log('yyyyy');
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

Trying to add data in Firebase Firestore,

Answer (score 0):

`addDoc` is an asynchronous operation. You need to use the `await` keyword to halt execution of your code until the document is added. Otherwise `docRef` will not represent your document.

```js
try {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    name: "Alan",
  });
  console.log('yyyyy');
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

Comment: I tried to work with this code but the data is not being added. I put console statements above and below the await statement. Only, the statement above the await statement is running.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
try {
  console.log
  const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    name: "Alan",
    //middle: "Mathison",
    //last: "Turing",
    //born: 1912
  }).then(res => {
    console.log('yyyyy');
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  });
  
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work. You can remove excessive `console.logs`

```js
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
  name: "Alan"
});
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
```